# Red5 Error "Scope Not Found"

Tags: java, server, red5

I have created a Red5 server project in Eclipse with the Red5 plugin. But every time i start the server i get an error "scope not found"

> [WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope not found
>   org.red5.server.exception.ScopeNotFoundException: Scope not found: bwcheck in null
>       at org.red5.server.scope.ScopeResolver.resolveScope(ScopeResolver.java:112)
>       at org.red5.server.Context.resolveScope(Context.java:158)
>       at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:323)
>       at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:116)
>       at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:72)
>       at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:38)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope bwcheck not found on localhost
>   [WARN] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Destination connection was null, it is already disposed. Session id: DSNGKAODSPSGV
>   [INFO] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed: DSNGKAODSPSGV
>   [WARN] [NioProcessor-14] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Connection was not found for DSNGKAODSPSGV
>   [INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] org.red5.server.tomcat.WarDeployer - Deploy wars with app start
>   [INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] org.red5.server.tomcat.WarDeployer - Deploy wars with app start